# How to unit test functions with $http.jsonp in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Here is part of my controller:

```
    $scope.isLoggedIn = function () {
        return Boolean($sessionStorage.isLoggedIn);
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
        //If the browser fills in the username and password field then angular's model will not be updated so we need
        //to manually pull them out of the DOM :(. See this issue for details: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1460
        var username = $('#usernameInput').val();
        var password = $('#passwordInput').val();
        $scope.loginErrMsg = null;

        $http.jsonp("http://ldap-auth.otpp.me" + '/login?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password))
            .success(function (data, isLoggedIn) {
                // This app is for internal use only, security is not a major concern.
                // So using sessionStorage to store the login status is OK.
                $sessionStorage.displayName = data.displayName;
                $sessionStorage.isLoggedIn = true;
            })
            .error(function () {
                $scope.loginErrMsg = "Invalid username or password";
            });
    };
```

Here is my test:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function () {

// load the controller's module
beforeEach(module('uiappApp'));

var MainCtrl,
    $httpBackend,
    scope;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');

}));
it('should login', function () {
    var isLoggedIn = scope.isLoggedIn();
    expect(isLoggedIn).toBe(false);

    var username = $('<input type="text" id="usernameInput"/>');
    var password = $('<input type="text" id="passwordInput"/>');
    $('body').html('<div>')
        .find('div')
        .append(username)
        .append(password);
    username.val('username');
    password.val('password');
    var response =  $httpBackend.expectJSONP('http://ldap-auth.otpp.me/login?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&username=username&password=password');
    response.respond({displayName: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});
    scope.login();
    expect(scope.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(true);
    $('body').empty();
    });
});
```

However the test always fails (`Expected false to equal true.`). It seems that I didn't get $httpBackend working. But I cannot figure out where was wrong. Basically I want to mock $http.jsonp() response to provide a mocked-up json when unit testing and then test the user login.

Thanks very much if you can help!

@HackedByChinese After folloing your step, I have:

```
it('should login', function () {
    var isLoggedIn = scope.isLoggedIn();
    expect(isLoggedIn).toBe(false);

    var username = $('<input type="text" id="usernameInput"/>');
    var password = $('<input type="text" id="passwordInput"/>');
    $('body').html('<div>')
        .find('div')
        .append(username)
        .append(password);
    username.val('username');
    password.val('password');
    var response =  $httpBackend.expectJSONP('http://ldap-auth.otpp.me/login?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&username=username&password=password');
    response.respond({displayName: 'userX'}, {'A-Token': 'xxx'});
    scope.login();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(true);
    $('body').empty();
});
```

But I got the following error message:

```
    Error: Unexpected request: GET views/main.html
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1177:9)
    at sendReq (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7967:9)
    at $get.serverRequest (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7708:16)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11100:81)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11100:81)
    at C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11186:26
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12175:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12004:31)
    at Function.$httpBackend.flush (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1435:16)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:/repo/docserver-ui/UIApp/test/spec/controllers/main.js:43:22)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

And here is my partial html:

```
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form" ng-show="!isLoggedIn()">
                <p class="navbar-text" id="loginErrMsg">{{loginErrMsg}}</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" id="usernameInput"
                           class="form-control"
                           ng-class="{'error-fields': loginErrMsg}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passwordInput" class="form-control" ng-class="{'error-fields': loginErrMsg}">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="login()">Sign in</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After calling `scope.login()` and before your `expect(...)`, you need to call `$httpBackend.flush()` for it to respond with the specified expectations.

This is not specific to JSONP, but unit testing `$http` calls in general.

To summarize, here are the steps to unit test code that makes `$http` requests:

1. Set up your expectations using `$httpBackend`.
2. Invoke the code that makes the `$http` call(s).
3. Call `$httpBackend.flush()` to make it respond to any pending requests with the expectations you set up.
4. Make your test assertions.

See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend#flushing-http-requests) regarding flush.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I still got error message: `Error: Unexpected request: GET views/main.html`. Details in my refined question. Thanks!

Comment: I added `$httpBackend.when('GET', 'views/main.html').respond();` then the problem is solved. But I'm not sure if this is just a random hack or the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: Is main.html part of your application? Is there code omitted from your question that later loads a template or tries to redirect to another route? If so, you are probably experiencing problems because you are mixing unit testing and end-to-end testing. While they appear similar, they have different purposes for good reason. Angular has recommendations for dedicated to both unit and E2E testing.

Comment: Yes, I have `$route.reload()` in $scope.logout(). Thanks very much for the clarification!

Comment: FYI, you could create a fake `$route` and add it as another property on the second parameter you pass to `$controller(...)` (where you specify `$scope: $scope`; same thing but with `$route`). If you create a spy on `$route.reload`, you can then test that it was called. This will ensure the functionality works without extra setup.